# Restore deleted folder from wiped SSD?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, restore

I'm not sure what happened, but when I updated my BIOS and booted into Windows, part of SSD#0 is gone. Not just deleted, but turned into unallocated space. It's a Kingston SV300 240gb SSD, split into a 50gb Windows partition (this was unaffected) and the remainder for a partition for a few but nevertheless extremely important data. I got a new HDD today to act as a backup, but as luck would have it, before I could install it and make duplicates of my important files, this happened.

The partition is now unallocated space. I know the folder names, but not specific file names. I need to recover these folders with some urgency. I've tried Recuva but it can't seem to target specific directories, only files of a given name or type. Additionally, Recuva can't scan unallocated space.

What can I do? I haven't done anything to the unallocated space: haven't created a new volume or anything.

Some things I know:

- TRIM is enabled
- I know the folder names
- Partition letter was M:\
- rough idea of total size of files deleted (<20gb)

Comment: Even on a standard HDD, there's no way your getting all 20GB back. That's an assumption being made regardless of knowing how much has been added/removed from the drive since data loss. The metadata  is absolutely lost which means sifting through the potentially recovered data is going to be a **daunting** task. The best suggestions I can make are Recuva and Active@ but Active@ isn't free and both will take several hours (over night) just to scan for files, **not** to recover them. Again, that's on a standard HDD, I don't even know if the best file recovery programs I know of offer SSD support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try easeus data recovery,  it will search deleted or lost partitions on the unallocated space of all hard disks. But it does not guaranteed, as SSD is different with Windows partition, as MrU say, all data on ssd is transferred almost instaneously.